# Eclipse Luna - Jboss 7 Servlet & JPA app servlet does not start

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, servlets, jpa

I have a JBoss AS 7 and Eclipse Luna project that is maven based.  I'm using an annotated servlet and have a very simple JPA entity  and DAO.

When I deploy via Eclipse, the servlet does not start.

If I `mvn package` and deploy via the JBOss web interface the servlet deploys.

With eclipse, the JPA classes deploy and the persistence stuff is setup, but I don't get anything from the servlet.

I do not have any XML files other than the persistence.xml, just the annotated servlet like so:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/simple"}, loadOnStartup=1)
public class EntityServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EJB EntityDao ed;

    public EntityServlet() {
        System.err.println("Starting servlet");
        System.err.println("ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ");
    }
    public void setEntityDao(EntityDao e){
        ed = e;
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

        out.print("<html><body>");
        out.print("<h3>Hello Servlet</h3><p>");
        out.print(ed.addNamedEntity("ADSF"));
        out.print("</p>");
        out.print("<p>" + ed.getAllNamedEntities() + "</p></body></html>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good grief, found the problem.

I noticed that my test cases were not compiling, so I started chasing that and found that my java builder in my .project file was no longer there ( no idea where the hell it went ).

[Here is the link to the fix for the compile problems](http://blog.mikeski.net/blog_post/384)

The gist of it is you have to add:

```
<buildCommand>
     <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
     <arguments>
     </arguments>
</buildCommand>
```

to your .project file in the buildSpec section if it is indeed missing.